# How to effortlessly export Jupyter Notebook's current/visible session into python source code

Tags: ipython, jupyter

**Context**: I was implementing fairly short program to solve algorithmic problems on hackerank on *jupyter notebook*. After finishing my program, I would need to select only the currently visible source from the *jupyter* session to submit. The invisible code are erroneous code which has been replaced, so I don't want them.
[image: my sample jupyter session]

As far as I know, the *export* function of *jupyter* will copy not only source but also line numbers, and so on.
The `%history` and `%save` doesn't provide the function I need also.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by invisible code (how is it invisible?) but you might want to take a look at the nbconvert docs, specifically [this part](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing.html) about custom templates.

If you want to remove markdown cells and remove prompt numbers (i.e. just have the source code), this is the template you want (saved as `mytemplate.tpl` in my example but feel free to name it anything with a `.tpl`):

```
{% extends 'python.tpl'%}

## remove markdown cells
{% block markdowncell %}
{% endblock markdowncell %}

## remove prompt
{% block in_prompt %}
{% endblock in_prompt %}
```

You can then convert using this tempalte with the command

`jupyter nbconvert --to python 'example.ipynb' --template=mytemplate.tpl`

Comment: Hello @Louise,
Thank for introducing the function of jupyter.

By invisible code, I means the previous commands on a cell which has been replaced by other commands. For example, at the picture of my above program, in the input no 7 `in[7]`, the code inside that cell is just the *newest version*, there was actually previous version of code inside this cell also, but not visible.